# ifstream размер файла, который я нахожу, больше реального

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream

Есть код для нахождения длины текстового файла в символах. Однако он находит длину этого файла большую, чем файл есть на самом деле.

Данная проблема точно не наблюдается в текстах состоящих только из символов `a..z` и `A..Z`. Однако, некоторые символы, такие как, например, перенос строки, как `а..я` и `А..Я`, а так же некоторые специальные символы, принимаются моим кодом за 2 символа.

Вот код:

```
size_t getfilesize(ifstream &file) {
    int old_pos = file.tellg();

    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int fileSize = file.tellg();

    file.seekg(old_pos);
    return fileSize;
}
```

Полагаю это потому, что мы, по сути, так находим длину файла в байтах, а не символах, и некоторые символы могут быть более длинными, чем 1 байт. Но я не уверен.

Подскажите, в чём природа этого явления и как можно найти размер в файла в символах по-хорошему?

Comment: Читать как `unsigned char`, а так все правильно, символы А-Я в юникода занимают больше одного unsigned char, в win это unsigned char[2] = wchar_t Некоторые символы в других алфавитах занимают до 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас, наверное, поток открыт как текстовый. Текстовые потоки не поддерживают функциональности

```
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
```

В текстовых потоках разрешается только делать `file.seekg(0, ios::begin);`, а также делать `ios_base::cur` на позицию, полученную из предыдущего вызова `tellg`.

Если вы хотите узнать размер файла, то поток должен открываться как бинарный.

Comment: Я открыл поток как бинарный, заменив ifstream `find_here(argv[1], fstream::in);` на `ifstream find_here(argv[1], fstream::binary);`, но этого явно недостаточно. Функция всё равно получает размер файла в символах больший, чем он есть на самом деле.

Comment: И перенос строки всё так же засчитывается в длину файла как два символа, вместо одного. Как и раньше.

Comment: @Егор Левоненко: Ну так так и должно быть. В общем случае не существует способа узнать размер текстового файла заранее, не прочитав его посимвольно. Это не сводится только к кодировке переводов строки, а также может запросто включать различные многобайтовые кодировки переменной ширины, вроде UTF-8 и UTF-16.

Comment: В таком случае, есть ли способ узнать, какой "размер" у какого-то определённого конкретного символа?

Comment: Читайте это все как wchar_t и используйте набор функций wcs(*)mbr/mbr(*)wcs

Comment: Тема очень расплывчатая, компьютеру по барабану, что вы считаете символом и он выдаёт только байты. В табуляции (код например 9) размер 1 байт, а вы считайте как хотите, четыре или восемь символов.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Но в данном случае речь идёт о "размере", который выдаст данная функция. Я просто не понимаю, как он находит для разных символов разный их размер, если, как я знаю, в файле с конкретной кодировкой все символы имеют фиксированную длину в байтах.

Comment: Текстовый файл с кодировкой UTF-8 может содержать английские буквы, русские, китайские, анаглифы, рисунки и т.д. У всех символов разный размер в байтах.(от одного до шести). В этом конкретно случае использовать надо не `ifstream`  , а `ifwstream`.